# Open in which topology? Seifert–Van Kampen theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness

Is a particular case of Seifert-Van Kampen theorem that if $U$ and $V$ are **open sets** simply connected and $U\cap V$ is path connected, then $X=U\cup V$ is simply connected.

I have dificulties with the **open**. At $U$ and $V$'s topologies, $U$ and $V$ are open, respectively. But what about the $X$ topology?

For instance, I would like to prove that the union of two spheres by a commom point is simply connected. How to state that each of these is open in the union?

Thank you.

Comment: You are given the topological space $X$ and cover it with two open sets $U,V$ in it.

Comment: They are both open in $X$'s topology.

Comment: $X=U\cup V$. Let $A\subseteq X$, then let $A$ be open $\Leftrightarrow A=U_0\cup V_0$, where $U_0$ is open in $U$ and $V_0$ is open in $V$. You can easily see that $X$ is also open under this rule.

Comment: One usually states this theorem by saying that $U, V$ are **open subsets** (or open subspaces) of $X$. See for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem).

Comment: @QiZhu, so maybe I should take $U$ and $V$ not the spheres, but the spheres plus something (a portion of the other sphere)?

Comment: @DuncanRamage, so maybe I should take $U$ and $V$ not the spheres, but the spheres plus something (a portion of the other sphere)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, so maybe I should take $U$ and $V$ not the spheres, but the spheres plus something (a portion of the other sphere)?

Comment: @Teddy38, so did you suggest that in that way I can construct the conveniente topology of $X$? thank you

Comment: You should not assume that these subsets are spheres.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you]

Comment: The spheres $S_1, S_2$ must have dimension $> 1$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, sure, thank you for addendum